# Draw polygon of 100 pixels on mouseclick

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to draw a square polygon of 100x100 screenpixels whereever I click on the Google map (Amsterdam, lat 52, lng 4), on every zoomlevel, with e.latlng at the center of the polygon. I tried to figure it out using fromLatLngToPoint, fromPointToLatLng, scale and worldCoordinates, but I can't get the polygon drawn. If someone likes this puzzle I would appreciate the solution very much. 
(I want to use this as a simple start to edit the polygon to a more complex shape, not using the DrawingManager)

I tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());
var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(e.latLng);
var deX = Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale);
var deY = Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale);

// so far so good, deX and deY give the centerpixel

var deNW = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(deX-50,deY-50));         
var deNO = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(deX+50,deY-50));
var deZO = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(deX+50,deY+50));
var deZW = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(deX-50,deY+50));

var dePathArray = [deNW, deNO, deZO, deZW]; 
deObjectNew = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: dePathArray,                         
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
}); 
deObjectNew.setMap(map);
```

});

Comment: Why don't you just make a 100x100 square marker and put that down at the mouse clicks?

Comment: Because I need a polygon to edit afterwards, not a marker.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
        var deNW = deKaart.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((deX-50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.x,(deY-50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.y));         
        var deNO = deKaart.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((deX+50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.x,(deY-50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.y));
        var deZO = deKaart.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((deX+50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.x,(deY+50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.y));
        var deZW = deKaart.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((deX-50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.x,(deY+50)/scale+worldCoordinateNW.y));
```